# ssh client closing window hook

Tags: ssh

I need to hook the moment when the client disconnected from the server.
I can hook it when user apply `exit` command (using ForceCommand). But when it just closes a window where ssh is running my approach does not work.

I want to hook the moment when the user closes terminal to notify other user who also logged in on this server.

Any suggestion?

Comment: not sure what type of hook you mean. You also don't mention if you want this on server or client side, which is quite a difference.
But if it is some kind of LD_PRELOAD, I recommend doing so on server side, where nobody can close the window. I guess session_close(), or do_cleanup() should do the job

Comment: If you run ssh in a terminal and you want to close the window when ssh exits just run `exec ssh ...` instead of `ssh ...`.

Comment: Jakuje, on a server side.

Comment: How do you make a hook using `ForceCommand` at present?